# Windows 7 laptop constantly dropping internet connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I have scoured the web for an answer and failed to find one.

I am using a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Windows 7 64-Bit. I have the computer connected via Wifi. Now, I am no beginner with the Internet, or anything related to computers, as I have grown up teaching everyone around me how to use computers, and went to college for IT. Everything on my network works flawlessly at all times, except for this evil laptop. The worst part is that I fixed this once before a few years back and recently had to replace the hard drive and re-install the OS, but cannot for the life of me remember what I did to make this problem go away.

I am in my browser, connected to the Internet. I click a link. Suddenly no internet access. All I do is click down on the WiFi connection in the task bar, disconnect and reconnect immediately. Internet is back the moment I hit "connect." I have read many people had the same issues as I am having, but they all had triggers or other network issues. I have no trigger (this happens literally five to six times per minute no matter what I am doing) and I have no problems with my router, modem, or any other devices or computers on said network. As I am a web designer, and like to test my work live at every turn- this is going to result in this laptop being in pieces if I can't get it fixed soon.

If more info is needed, let me know and I will provide. Thanks for any help offered!

EDIT:

Network Card: Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
Network state reads as "No Internet Access" when the problem first occurs, then magically I have Internet access for about ten seconds once I disconnect and reconnect.

I have turned off IPV6, I have turned off power saving options for the network adapter, no viruses. Any new ideas? Also, I had to disconnect and reconnect four times just to get to this edit screen- and will likely have to do the same just to post it- it's that bad.

Comment: What WiFi network adapter are you using?

Comment: laptop model name?

Comment: When you have no internet what is the status of the WiFi adapter? During this period of dropped connection, can you still ping or access local files? Does this occur with any browser? Does this issue happen on a different network? Does it happen with your firewall off?

Comment: I'm just taking a stab at what you might have done to fix it the first time. Did your original fix have something to do with a power-saving setting? Maybe you ended up installing a non-standard or out-of-date Wi-Fi driver rather than using the latest available one? Did you physically remove the Wi-Fi card and plug it back in?

Comment: If you do a `ping -t google.com` from the CMD window, what happens when your web browsing cuts out? Could be a virus...

Comment: @Ramhound Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC. -STTR As mentioned in my OP, Toshiba Satellite. -MonkeyZeus I did try making it so there were no power saving options turned on for the wireless network adapter at all. When I check for driver updates it says none found, so I'm not sure if I have the latest or not? I did not physically remove the card, and since I didn't have to do that the first time I'm thinking that wouldn't solve my issue this time around either. No viruses, I have this thing secured like fort knox, lol.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, it comes back with Pinging www.google.com [74.125.228.20] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.27: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.27: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.27: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.27: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.27: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about all the troubles, is the laptop still under warranty? Can you call Toshiba?

Comment: If you do a `ping -t` directly to your router's IP address then does it cut out as well? My router is 192.168.1.1 and there is a good chance yours is as well. If you cannot find it then open a CMD window and do an `ipconfig` and look for the `Default Gateway`

Comment: You said you had to re-install the OS correct? Did Toshiba supply a restore DVD(s) for this or did you make your own the first time around? I am wondering if Toshiba provided some sort of WiFi management software that could be interfering with the Windows built-in Wifi management. Also, do things work fine if you plug in with an Ethernet cable? <-- I know it's not an optimal solution but I am curious for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Please provide driver details ( I.e. driver version )

Comment: @Ramhound Driver version 1002.2.428.2010, it says it is the most current driver.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, it tells me Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Corbin>ping -t 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=890ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=886ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, also- I had to order Toshiba's 3-disc "back to out of box" recovery set. I can't find any sort of WiFi management but I am unsure of what I am looking for, lol. I will have to try to use the ethernet cord a bit later. I have it in my head I tried that back when I first had this issue and it worked fine when plugged in. But, I believe it also has a separate card for the WiFi and another for the Ethernet cord so I don't know if that would help us debug? Thanks for all your input thus far, much appreciation! My problems seem to be worse than ever before at the moment.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I can't take it anymore, I'm going to run this laptop over with my truck until I run out of gas.  It's at the point where I am literally disconnecting and reconnected before I click anything in my browser. I can't test my sites live, I can't run my jquery databases, I can't do anything- I'm freaking out. It works perfectly plugged in but the way my house is set up that just is not really optional. If I put in a new wireless network card, will my problems be gone?

Comment: Lol at the truck idea, I am honestly out of ideas. If a new wireless card isn't too expensive I would give it a go. How does it act with a wireless network that's not your own? Can you go to a StarBucks or somewhere else with free public WiFi? A friends' house?

Comment: How is this going for you?

Answer (score 2):

This could likely be due to a power setting. Access your Device Manager and go to the properties for your wireless interface card. In the Advanced tab (or with certain models/drivers there is a "Power Management" tab), there are several power options in this section that may disable your wifi card over time.

I've sometimes deleted the wireless NIC from the device manager to let my computer reinstall it to resolve issues similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot... but I've had similar experiences which I resolved by locking my router to a particular channel.

Most routers nowadays are set to hunt out a quiet(er) channel if they experience heavy traffic  (collisions?).  Additionally, many are set to prefer to use channels 1, 6 or 11 (802.11bgn 2GHz).  I found that using channel 3 is best for my area, with another option being ch 9.

Try locking your router to a single channel, turning off the 'select best channel...' options.

Seems that the router is jumping channels to find a less noisy frequency, and Windows then has to go hunting for it, taking time, 'dropping' the connection in the mean time.

If you're an Android user, the "Wifi Analyzer" app by Farproc is very useful to show channel usage in your area.

[Wifi Analyzer by Farproc (Google Play)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when only on battery power or when using AC power as well?

If this is only happening when you are running on your battery, check your power saver settings, as it may be putting your laptops WiFi adapter into a mode in which it uses less power.

Have you checked for an updated driver? Also, is this card an N100?

Comment: I pretty much never use the laptop whilst plugged in, but I will give it a shot to see if it works better or not. I did turn off the power saving nonsense which did not help. I checked for an updated driver and it said none found. Unsure of what N100 is, but I edited my OP to include what the card is if that answers it?

Comment: That does not tell what strength the card is, but no worries. Try updating your driver as a first step (if it isnt up to date already). Also, is it possible for you to post a few screenshots of your router BIOS? Some details about it (model, etc). You may be having an issue with upnp if it is enabled, or another BIOS setting.

Comment: Drivers are up to date. I know for sure it has nothing to do with the router, as every device on the network works perfectly, and always has. I can be connected via WiFi with ten different devices and still get 50mbps over the air to all of them without ever skipping a beat. It's this evil, evil, evil laptop. Honestly, it seems the problem has gotten worse since I started trying to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've ran in to this issue, it's been the wireless card "slowly" dying. I've had multiple friends call me in to troubleshoot this same issue on Toshiba Satellite series laptops before. I'm gonna take a wild guess and say the laptop is older than 2008. Sometimes, components just fry before their designated lifespan.

It isn't much of a fix, but I recommend just getting a new wireless card or disabling it & using a USB wireless dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Another area to examine is interference on the wifi channel your router is using.  Not sure what happened in my neighborhood but some wifi device using the same channel was constantly forcing my laptop nic to reset but after changing router to different channel, this seems to have stopped....if you download wifi analyzing tools, you might also see what's happening in your zone

Answer (score -1):

Probably driver related, I have had the same with my wifi-card in my computer. There was no real official driver for Windows 8, so I had to use the Windows 7 one. It worked great in Windows 7 but in W8 it dropped connection randomly or when it was intensively used.

--

Have you tried reinstalling the driver? I have had this same issue before as I stated above, but apparently people need to downvote me even though I am providing you help.

1) De-install your current wireless driver
2) Go to company's website of your laptop (Toshiba) and look for your model. Download the drivers provided there (not the ones provided by Windows Update or Realtek
3) If this problem persists, then we have ruled out a driver related issue (as everything will be resetted to default with Toshiba's default settings) and the only area where things could go wrong would be third-party software interfering with your wireless network card, or a hardware malfunction.

Comment: User is not using Windows 8

Comment: User is using Windows 7, I am pointing out that I had the same problem, under Windows 8. So maybe he's got a malfunctioning driver, causing the same issues which I had under a different Operating System, but which MIGHT be replicated under an older OS.

Comment: You referenced "no real driver" or an unofficial driver as an issue with windows 8 (which I experienced), not malfunctioning. Stock drivers exist for network devices on Windows 7...most network drivers are Intel or Realtek.

Comment: most network drivers are Intel or Realtek, correct, the OP however does not clarify which drivers he is using (maybe he has a different brand than Intel or Realtek) therefor I point him in a certain direction saying that it might be driver related.

Comment: Would have made more sense if you had worded it that way the first time. And doubtful it's anything other than those two, usually see Intel on Toshiba.

Comment: Update this question to be more specific to the user's situation and I will remove downvote